# params in url with PHP

Tags: php, get

I have a url `http://localhost/test/index.php?url=test/index?id=123&version=3`, 
when I `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` it output `string 'url=test/index?id=123&version=3' (length=31)` but when I `$_GET['url']` it output `string 'test/index?id=123' (length=17)`. So what hell going wrong? What I am doing wrong?
Expected string: `test/index?id=123&version=3`

Comment: Ampersand ends up the current URL param and begins the next one.

Comment: `$_GET['version']` outputs 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` character separates key-value pairs in query strings.

If you want to pass one as data you have to percent-encode it: `%26`

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)/[`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode)